# Calculation of the sub gradient of the first norm of a matrix

Tags: normed-spaces, absolute-value, subgradient

Lets say I have a matrix X and its first norm $||X||_1$. How do I calculate the subgradient of this norm with respect to matrix X itself.

Comment: @julien. X is of size nxn. The norm is on the coefficients of X

Comment: @julien. I was actually reading this paper http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/graph.pdf where they take the derivation of the first norm of the precision matrix Q or lets say lasso penalty of an objective function. Then they say the derivative is given by matrix $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_{ij} = Sign(Q_{ij})$ if $Q_{ij}$ != 0 and $\Gamma_{ij}$ $\epsilon$ [-1 1] if  $Q_{ij}$ = 0